# I Want to pass Jenkins parameters into a build DSL Script. It is not taking this parameter.

Tags: jenkins, dsl

I have defined a build flow with the following script in Jenkins in a Build Flow

```
Build("Server Repository","ENV")
```

where ENV is a choice parameter defined in the Build Flow Item.When I am building it is not at all using my chosen parameter. It is taking default and same values at every build.

```
Build("Server Repository",$ENV)
```

Has been also tried. It does not work.Plus declaring Jenkins Parameters too have been tried.

```
ENV=${ENV}
Build("Server Repository",ENV)
```

Has been tried too. Suggest some possible ways to work this out.